# Polymer:how to handle csv file upload and convert to json and send to server

Tags: polymer, vaadin

i want to handle a requirement in polymer webcomponents where user can upload csv file from ui and csv file can be parsed to json and sent to server ,i searched and found for vaadin upload,looked over the api but i am not sure how to receive  the csv file and convert to json  and sent to server,can anyone show a jsfiddle of vaadin upload or any other web component to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am wondering why you would not simply do the conversion on the server side.

In this case, you would be able to use the [vaadin-upload](https://vaadin.com/elements/-/element/vaadin-upload#docs) directly indeed.

Here is a snippet that would upload all files to the example.com server, and only allow CSV files.

```
<vaadin-upload target="https://example.com/upload" method="POST" accept="text/csv">
</vaadin-upload>
```

There are plenty of resources on how to convert CSV files to JSON.

- [Here is a snippet](https://gist.github.com/iwek/7154578)
- [And here is a node library](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson)

If you really wanted to do the conversion client side, then I would suggest to create an element that would **embed a vaadin-upload**, and convert the [Files](https://vaadin.com/elements/-/element/vaadin-upload#vaadin-upload:property-files) array to Json before manually calling the [**uploadFiles**](https://vaadin.com/elements/-/element/vaadin-upload#demos) method.